# Looking for a fix for Swift "ambiguous use of 'object(forKey:)'"

Tags: swift, anyobject

I've inherited some Swift code that I'm trying to compile.

The following two lines generate an "Ambiguous use of object(forKey:)" error.

```swift
let selectorString: String = (req as AnyObject).object(forKey: "selectorString") as! String
let args = (req as AnyObject).object(forKey: "arguments") as! NSArray
```

The error highlights `req as AnyObject` as the culprit.

I've found similar issues on S.O., but none seemed to address this particular issue. I may have missed something in the search results.

I'm hoping this is a simple fix, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the type of req object before casting to AnyObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything depends on what `req` is. If it is something that can be cast as AnyObject and that responds to `object(forKey:)`, your code compiles and runs. For example:

```
let req : [String:Any] = ["selectorString":"hey", "arguments":["ho"]]
let selectorString: String = (req as AnyObject).object(forKey: "selectorString") as! String
let args = (req as AnyObject).object(forKey: "arguments") as! NSArray
```

However, if `req` cannot be cast to AnyObject, you'll get a compile error.

Comment: Also this might depend on what version of Swift you are using.